grid-auto-flow: dense not working with responsive grid layout
In my responsive two column layout, I want items to have their own height, I don't want them to share the same height of the items next to them. I'm using Tailwind, JavaScript & React. gridAutoFlow: "column dense" in my Grid component isn't working, & I don't understand why?
Thank-you!

Grid component:
import { CssClassName, cssMerge } from "@utils/tailwind"
import { PropsWithChildren, useMemo } from "react"

/**
 * Responsive grid that centers its children.
 */
export default function ({
    cols,
    rows,
    className,
    gap = 0,
    gridBreakpoint = "grid",
    children,
}: Props) {
    const classNames = useMemo(() => {
        const classNames = [
            gridBreakpoint,
            `gap-${gap}`,
            `grid-cols-${cols || 1}`,
            `grid-rows-${rows || "auto"}`,
            "items-start",
        ]

        return cssMerge(classNames, className)
    }, [cols, rows, className])

    const gridStyles = {
        display: "grid",
        gridAutoFlow: "column dense",
    }

    return (
        <div
            className={classNames}
            style={gridStyles}
        >
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

type Props = PropsWithChildren<
    {
        gap?: number
        className?: CssClassName
        gridBreakpoint?: `${"" | "xs:" | "sm:" | "md:" | "lg:"}grid`
    } & (
        | {
              cols: number
              rows?: undefined
          }
        | {
              cols?: undefined
              rows: number
          }
    )
>

Profile component:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Grid from "../../../components/layout/Grid"



export default function Profile() {
    const [isTwoCols, setIsTwoCols] = useState(false)
    const [isSevenCols, setIsSevenCols] = useState(false)

    function logWindowWidth() {
        const width = window.innerWidth
        console.log("Window width:", width)

        setIsTwoCols(width > 760 && width < 1350)
        setIsSevenCols(width >= 1350)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        // Set initial values
        logWindowWidth()

        // Add event listener for resize
        window.addEventListener("resize", logWindowWidth)

        // Cleanup the event listener on component unmount
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", logWindowWidth)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Grid
            cols={isTwoCols ? 2 : isSevenCols ? 8 : 1}
            gap={5}
        >
            <div className="col-span-1 border border-green-500">
                <b>User Details </b>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    Aliquam euismod blandit neque a pretium. Cras posuere quis
                    diam fringilla condimentum. Phasellus non dolor metus. Donec
                    nibh ante, dapibus ut est molestie, volutpat sodales erat.
                    Mauris eget posuere tortor. Curabitur vel porttitor quam
                </p>
                <p>
                    Nullam rhoncus nisl sed scelerisque aliquam. Donec eleifend
                    nec magna nec luctus. Nam elementum eu turpis quis varius.
                    Aenean imperdiet viverra nibh, et elementum odio. Aenean
                    luctus mattis quam, a congue massa malesuada id. Sed a velit
                    a leo molestie ultricies.
                </p>
            </div>

            {(isTwoCols || isSevenCols) && (
                <>
                    <div className="col-start-1 row-start-2  border border-green-500">
                        <b>Messages</b>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                            elit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-start-2 row-start-1  border border-green-500">
                        <div className="flex flex-col p-3 ">
                            <b>Roles</b>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                adipiscing elit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-start-2 row-start-2  border border-green-500">
                        <div className="flex flex-col p-3 ">
                            <b>Teams</b>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                adipiscing elit.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
            <div
                className={`${
                    isTwoCols
                        ? "col-start-2 row-start-3"
                        : isSevenCols
                        ? "col-start-3 row-start-1"
                        : ""
                }  border border-green-500`}
            >
                <b>Email address</b>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div
                className={`${
                    isTwoCols
                        ? "col-start-2 row-start-4 "
                        : isSevenCols
                        ? "col-start-3 row-start-2"
                        : ""
                } border border-green-500`}
            >
                <b>Password details</b>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            {!isTwoCols && !isSevenCols && (
                <>
                    <div className="flex flex-col p-3  border border-green-500">
                        <b>Roles</b>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                            elit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col p-3  border border-green-500">
                        <b>Teams</b>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                            elit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <b>Messages</b>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    </p>
                </>
            )}
        </Grid>
    )
}


that looks like you want the layout called "masonry". unfortunately, this layout cannot be made yet in css, you need javascript to do that : https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns
